# BiqQuery which tool is used to produce reports online?

Tags: report, google-bigquery

I'am new to BigQuery and I come to Google cloud from "oracle forms/reports"...
Can someone give me some direction which tool is used to produce some kind of report connected to BigQuery? 
For now I have tried to export BigQuery datas into CSV and use that data in Excel or some other program..

thank you

Comment: in general @pentium 10's answer to this is good. However, a lot of these tools have free editions for short terms. If you are serious about finding a better solution(as excel is rarely the best solution) play with the free editions to decide what fits you best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if your output fits in Excel and you are experienced there go ahead with that.

Other tools are:

- [Tableau](http://www.tableau.com/solutions/google-bigquery)
- [Shufflepoint](https://www.shufflepoint.com/Solutions.aspx)
- [QlikView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwXnB1TGakg) + [Demo](http://us-d.demo.qlik.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs/American%20Birth%20Statistics.qvw)
- [Bime Analytics + Demo](https://showcase.bime.io/dashboard/BigBigQuery#%2F)
- [Jaspersoft](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/google-bigquery-connector)
- [Metric Insights](http://www.metricinsights.com/solutions/big-data-analytics/google-bigquery-analytics-visualization/)
- [R](https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery)
- Today re:dash has support for querying multiple databases, including: Redshift, Google BigQuery, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Graphite and custom scripts.

You can try out the demo instance: http://demo.redash.io/ (login with any Google account). and find the repo at https://github.com/EverythingMe/redash

If you have GCE (Google Compute Engine) you can run your own private instance:

Instructions: https://github.com/EverythingMe/redash/wiki/Setting-up-re:dash-instance
Currently: `gcutil addimage redash-040b563 gs://redash-images/redash-040b563.tar.gz`

Also there are a bunch of other ETL tools listed on 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/third-party-tools

- Informatica
- Pervasive
- Talend
- SQLstream
- Simba (ODBC)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that if you're exporting to csv and importing it into excel, you can skip the export step and use the bigquery excel connector (described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-connector-for-excel), an excellent how-to video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udZNmb3QFQI))

Furthermore, you can also query BigQuery via AppsScript to use with Google Spreadhsheets (docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery), video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOynZLV4pYA))